# Meteor - How to create a page views or hits count like StackOverFlow's

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I wanted to ask if someone could help me making reactive page views for individual posts page.

I thought about using google analytics and using their api to display the post views but I dont want to go that route.

Rather something built in the app and most likely using the help of the iron router.

This is what I have so far in my router to display an individual post:

```
Router.route('/:slug', function () {
    this.render('showPost', {
        data: function() {
            return {
                post: Posts.findOne({slug: this.params.slug})
            };
        }
    });
}, {
    name: 'showPost'
});
```

And in the server side for inserting posts:

```
Posts.insert({
        createdAt: new Date(),
        updatedAt: new Date(),
        ownerId: Meteor.userId(),
        title: title,
        slug: slug,
        text: text,
        views: 0
    });
```

Comment: did you already check this [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13776820/meteor-template-reload-infinity)?

Comment: Thanks so much @Ethaan your comment helped me directly in resolving the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use iron router hooks for incrementing hit counts each time a page is being called. Something like this;

```
onBeforeAction: function () {
  Posts.update(
   {_id: this.params._id},
   {$inc: {'views': 1}}
  );
}
```